# How to designate caller from a call back

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set the 'this' or caller of a function yet set that as a callback?

```
this.CallServer({ url: 'myurl', success: F.call(myDOMElement) });

F function(data){ $(this).text(data); }
```

I realize that I can wrap the callback function and pass the DOMElement as a param calling F like below but I was wondering if there is a way to do it closer to above.

```
this.CallServer({url: 'myurl', success: function(data){F(data, myDOMElement);}});
F function(data, elem){ $(elem).text(data); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.CallServer({ url: 'myurl', success: F.bind(myDOMElement) });
```

`bind` will return the same function, except that it has a fixed value of `this` whenever called.

[Docs, including shim for older browsers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Simply speaking, `bind` could be defined as:

```
func.bind = function(thisValue) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(thisValue);
    };
};
```

E.g.

```
var func = function() { return this };
var bound = func.bind([1, 2, 3]);
var result = bound(); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much for the hasty reply.